# как сбрасывать обращение к слайдеру на минимум

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пишу программку в Unity2D на C#.
Есть код в котором при очередном срабатывании движение слайдера начинается не с начала. подскажите как "обнулять" слайдер.
вот кусок кода

```
void Update() {
    if (OnOf == true)
    {

        sliderF.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        sliderF.value += 1f;
        if (sliderF.value >= 100)
        {
                sliderF.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                IsButtonT.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                FX += Ra;
                FTextUI.text = FX.ToString();
                sliderF.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                IsButtonT.gameObject.SetActive(false);

                OnOf = false;

        }
    }

    if (OnOf == false)
    {
        sliderF.value -= 1;

    }
}

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    OnOf = true;
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    OnOf = false;
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, что за "срабатывание", приведите полный код.

Comment: И это все еще не весь код. Какой тип у sliderF? В каком месте он обнулятися? Какие минимальные и максимальные значения?

Answer (score 0):

Вы при выключении всего лишь один раз вычитаете `1` из значения слайдера

попробуйте так:

```
if (OnOf)
{
    ...
}
else 
{
    sliderF.value = 0;
}
```

ну или какое там у вас минимальное значение слайдера

---

И пожалуйста, не надо писать в условиях:

```
if (OnOf == true){}
if (OnOf == false){}
```

Пишите

```
if (OnOf){}
if (!OnOf){}
```

:)

Comment: @Валерий вы начало ответа прочитали? :)